# Convert and store integer into char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, printf

I am trying to convert and store an integer into a char pointer. So far this is what I have.

```
char * str1;
sprintf(str1,"%d",10);
```

I keep getting a `Segmentation fault` error.

If the code below works then why doesn't the above?

```
char * str1;
str1 = "Hello World";
printf("%s\n", str1);
```

Comment: You don't allocate memory for the string.

Comment: (**this is NOT a correct solution**) to sotre a integer into *pointer*, `sprintf((char*)&str1,"%d",10);` won't cause segmentation falut if ponters' size in your system is 3 bytes or more.

Comment: @MikeCAT its a typo

Comment: The second code will work because it is initialized to a valid pointer to read and nothing wrong is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ovious there was no memory to store the chars

```
char * str1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*10); //#include <stdlib.h> for malloc to allocate memory for keeping the chars
sprintf(str1,"%d",10);
```

May be you are new to c language, use char array instead of pointer to avoid confusion.

```
char str1[10]; // this will allocate memory while defination
sprintf(str1,"%d",10);
```

Two methods are quiet different but in this problem any can be used

Comment: should add that `#include <stdlib.h>` is required.

Comment: That's quiet obvious

Comment: Not if your new to C

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `char *str` doesn't create a piece of memory. It simply states that you have a pointer with type `char *` and the identifier `str`.

### Stack allocation

beware theres limited stack space and you can't return `str` from a function where statically allocated

```
char str[10];
sprintf(str1,"%d",10);
```

### Heap allocation

beware, to avoid memory leaks, `free` *has to be called* after you're done with the string.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...
char *str = malloc(10);
sprintf(str1,"%d",10);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, before you can use

```
 sprintf(str1,"%d",10);
```

you need to allocate memory for `str1`. Otherwise, you'll end up using uninitialized memory which may point to invalid memory location which in turn invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Considering an array,  like

```
char str1[32] = {0};
snprintf(str1, 31, "%d",10);
```

can do the job for you.

In the second case, `str1` is not *uninitialized*, it points to the starting of the string literal, so the access is valid.